# SLF4J, To avoid writing LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClassName.class) every time

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I am writing a web application in Java and using SLF4J for logging.

I'm becoming tired of writing the below line for every class that uses logging:

```java
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThisClassName.class);
```

To avoid redundant codes, I am thinking something like

```java
interface Loggable {
    Logger logger();
}
```

and each class can just implement this interface then some magic like AOP inserts the `LoggerFactory` part.

Has anyone implemented this or knows how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using eclipse? If so, why not just use a code template with a keyword like "logger" and the following template for it:

```
${:import(org.slf4j.LoggerFactory, org.slf4j.Logger)}
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);
```

This way you would just type "logger", hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and you are done.

Comment: Exactly, simple and does the job. Employing AOP just for such trivial issue is a crazy idea IMHO (especially if your project is not configured for AOP yet)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using CDI? if so, create a producer method and then @Inject the logger to any CDI enabled class.

```
@Produces Logger createLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) { 
    return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName()); 
}
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#d0e1662

Answer (score 0):

Logging using AOP is nicely demonstrated in [Here](http://developers-blog.org/blog/default/2009/07/13/Spring-AOP-Example).
There seems no way where we can dynamically insert logger inside a method to log the details of method execution. Unit test cases can take care of that.
Logging of method calling can be taken care by AOP

Answer (score 0):

if you are using @Slf4j annotation on your class then lombok will generate a variable 'log' by default

```
@Slf4j
public class YourClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        log.error("Test log");
    }
}
```

see the link
https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/154#issuecomment-163940867